# How can I lock the zoom in QGIS 2.6?

Tags: qgis, print-composer, zoom

I would like to make 10 maps over the exact same area. How can I lock the view in QGIS so I don't accidentally change it.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Answer (score 2):

In the items list of the print composer you can lock the map item by checking the box found under the padlock.  This will prevent any and all changes to that item.

Also, under the Item properties, Layers tab, you can check 'Lock layers' and 'Lock styles for layers'.  With the map item unchecked and these two items checked you can set up several other maps of the same area, showing different layers or styles, without changing the layers or style in your first map.[image]

If this is for the map window and not the print composer you can set up bookmarks, making it easier to return to specific locations and scales.

Comment: Thank you! How do I lock it in the QGIS window, it's there I got most of the problem.

Comment: I'm afraid I can't think of a way to lock the main window.  Like I said using bookmarks will allow to return to views you've created.  There's also a padlock next to the scale dropdown (in 2.16 that I'm using) at the bottom centre of the software window.  This will lock any scale dependent styles, but you can still "zoom" in and out by changing the mangification.  That could be the closest I get to a solution for you.

Comment: @Gremby - I also think using a **bookmark** is your best option here.

Answer (score 1):

We've found the best way to do this is to fix the extents of your print composer window using the Data Defined Override for the XMIN/YMIN/XMAX/YMAX values of your composer window.

Once you've found the right extent for your maps, copy each of the X min / Y min / etc. values and paste them into the 4 expression builders.

That way your map extent can't change even if you have changed the extent in the main QGIS window:

[image]